# accessing the result of a node twitter api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

OK I am running twitter script from node.js and I get the result in the console, say a users tweets. But what I want to do is have those tweets in the webpage. How do I do that? I thought perhaps I could send the username to a server running locally which calls node and that spits out the tweets but I'm not sure how to do that. any ideas appreciated

Comment: Why can't you call the twitter API from the browser?

Comment: you need Oauth - this program: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter does that for you